# Micronaut HttpClients exchange body is always null

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-client

I have setup a simple test Controller:

```java
@Controller("/test")
public class SampleController {
  @Get(value = "1", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String helloWorld1() {
    return "Hello, World!";
  }

  @Get(value = "2", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public HttpResponse<String> helloWorld2() {
    return HttpResponse.ok("Hello, World!");
  }
}
```

And I am using the low-level HTTPClient in my Unit-Tests, which looks like this:

```java
@MicronautTest
public class SampleControllerTest {

  @Inject
  EmbeddedServer server;

  @Inject
  @Client("/test")
  HttpClient client;

  @Test
  void shouldReturnHelloWorld1_1() {
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.toBlocking().exchange(HttpRequest.GET("/1").accept(
        MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

    assertEquals(200, response.code());
    assertEquals("Hello, World!", response.body());
  }

  @Test
  void shouldReturnHelloWorld1_2() {
    String response = client.toBlocking().retrieve(HttpRequest.GET("/1").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

    assertEquals("Hello, World!", response);
  }

  @Test
  void shouldReturnHelloWorld2() {
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.toBlocking().exchange(HttpRequest.GET("/2").accept(
        MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

    assertEquals(200, response.code());
    assertEquals("Hello, World!", response.body());
  }
}
```

From my understanding the response body should never be null, however it is for the tests `shouldReturnHelloWorld2` and `shouldReturnHelloWorld1_1` - so it is always null when `HttpClient.exchange()` is used.
In my opinion this seems to be bug or is here any issue?

You can check the whole code and run the tests yourself by cloning my sample repository: https://github.com/tobi6112/micronaut-httpclient-issue

**Update:**
Just noticed that the tests work as expected with

```java
HttpResponse<String> response = client.toBlocking()
        .exchange(HttpRequest.GET("/2").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN), String.class);
```

Comment: i suggest checking with a breakpoint if the dedicated controller functions are called as expected, maybe that could help you

Comment: "From my understanding the response body should never be null" - I don't think that is a correct understanding.  The docs at https://docs.micronaut.io/2.5.4/api/io/micronaut/http/HttpResponse.html#body-- say that the method returns "The body or null".

Comment: The edit that you made to the question should allow the `.body()` method to return non-null.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Yes that work's perfectly fine. However, according to the docs of the BlockingHttpClient https://docs.micronaut.io/2.1.3/api/io/micronaut/http/client/BlockingHttpClient.html#exchange-io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest- the parameter should not be required as it can be inferred from the generic type of `HttpResponse`. Maybe I'm wrong but this is my expectation from the docs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case these two options work:

```
final var result = client.toBlocking().exchange(HttpRequest.GET(url).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), String.class);

HttpResponse<String> response  = client.toBlocking().exchange(HttpRequest.GET(url).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), String.class);
```